# How to find the origin of the token/crypto in the wallet?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, alchemy, api

For example,
Wallet `0x...A1` has `0.5 ETH`. I want to know about the origin of `0.5 ETH`.
Can I get that data from the Etherscan API (what endpoint?) or another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using https://platform.arkhamintelligence.com/
it is definitely helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I wanna try it.